# react native: how to use renderScrollComponent within listview

Tags: listview, scroll, react-native

I want to use the listview do pull down load and pull up refresh of the component,
But I don't know how to use 'renderScrollComponent'.Maybe I should use ScrollView?

Comment: I found this question with the same doubt, I've managed to achieve the same result using ScrollView, so you might as well give it a try as well (in case you haven't already).